# Managing e-mail and spam?

Tags: email, monitoring, email-server, spam, exim

Running a CPanel server and just wondering what would be the best way to monitor incoming and outgoing e-mail to check for spam and other related attacks.

Currently, I am using exim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cPanel has [SpamAssassin support built into it](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SpamAssassin). That's enough for almost all scenarios unless you're doing something unusual.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to SpamAssassin you can use fail2ban to control bruteforce attacks on the server.

look at this howto: [Install Shorewall and Fail2Ban on a cPanel server](http://disstress.net/gen/install-shorewall-and-fail2ban-on-a-cpanel-server)